# How to prevent proprietary R package from being updated and replaced by CRAN package of the same name?

Tags: r

Suppose I'm using a proprietary R package named `ABC`. I use `devtools::install()` to build and install the package locally.

If one day, a package with the same name is released to CRAN, then I'll get a update notice if I call `update.packages()` if the CRAN version happens to use a higher version number.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can keep `ABC` from being updated and replaced by any remotes unless I install through `devtools::install()` or from `R CMD INSTALL` commands.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution (appart from renaming your local package to something like `ABClocal`) _prior_ to the name being published on CRAN (or elsewhere). For naming future package, I suggest you use `available::available("ABC")` which can check whether this problem will occur (but again, it won't work if a new package `ABC` gets published on CRAN one second after using `available`)...